# Time scaling in Laplace transformation

Tags: laplace-transform

A Laplace transform property: $f(at)\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{a}F(\frac{s}{a})$ where $f\leftrightarrow F$. Question: Is $a>0$ necessary for this property?

Comment: For $a<0$ define $g(bt)=g(-at)=f(at)$ and consider the Laplace transform of $g(bt)$

Comment: Dear Urgje, I would appreciate your giving specific example with a conclusion. Thanks.

Comment: The definition of the Laplace transform shows you that scaling with negative $a$ changes the integration interval into $(-∞,0]$. Alternatively you can scale with $|a|$.